# Populating select box options from previous select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting problem while populating select box options depend on previous select box

Problem is Whenever I select the value from first select box (i.e. #city) it gives me the result of city value which is fine but as soon as I select the second value it gives me the result of second values as well as first values.

below is my code

HTML CODE

```
<lable>City</lable>
<select id="city" style="width:100%;text-align:left;" onchange="getSchool()"></select>
<span id='paymentform_city_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<br>
<br>
<lable>School</lable>
<select id="school" style="width:100%;">

</select>
<span id='paymentform_school_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<br>
<br>
```

JS CODE

```
 var cityname, city, schoolname, schooldata, cityid, city1;
            var cityarray = [];
            var schoolarray = [];

            function getCity() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: baseurl + "getcity.php",

                    async: true
                    , success: function (data) {
                        data = $.trim(data);
                        if (data == "false") {
                            console.log(data);

                        } else {

                            var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                            jQuery(myArray).each(function (index, element) {
                                cityname = element.cityname;
                                cityid = element.city_id;
                                cityarray.push([cityname, cityid])
                            });
                            for (var i = 0; i < cityarray.length; i++) {
                                city1 += '<option value="' + cityarray[i][1] + '">' + cityarray[i][0] + '</option>';

                            }

                            $('#city').html("<option disabled selected></option>" + city1);
                        }
                    }

                });
            }

  function getSchool() {
            var city_id = $('#city').val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: baseurl + "getschool.php"
                , data: 'cityid=' + city_id
                , type: "POST"
                , success: function (response) {
                    response = $.trim(response);
                    if (response == "false") {

                               $('#school').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

                    } else {
                        $('#school').prop('disabled', false);
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#school').append(response);


                    }

                }
                , error: function () {}
            });
        }
```

Comment: you have to empty your div before inserting something into it ..add `$('#school').empty();` just beore `$('#school').append(response);`

Answer (score 1):

```
 function getSchool() {
            var city_id = $('#city').val();
            schoolarray = []; //Add this code.
```

Make the above change. And your school array will reset every-time a new city is selected.